# How do I get border-width of element with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, border

My CSS class:
    `.oriz_menu{
        font-size           :   18px;
        border-top          :   3px ridge darkred;
        border-bottom       :   3px ridge darkred;
        border-right        :   3px ridge darkred;
}`
Then when I try to get the border width it shows 0px:
`console.log($("#menu").css("border-top-width"));`

I have also tried `.css("borderTopWidth"))`
Please help!
PS: I append the #menu element into a parent then set the class with `$("#menu").addClass("oriz_menu")`

Comment: aside your question, why do you need to retrieve this value ?

Comment: Not sure if related but your selectors do not match? In your css you have .oriz_menu but in your question you have #menu

Comment: My browser is returning 3px -> **http://jsfiddle.net/Dp5CX/**

Comment: @Godinall the #menu element also has the .oriz_menu class

Comment: please provide `html` part too

Comment: @AmitSoni The #menu div is not in html. I append it to a parent element. Then I set width, height and add the .oriz_menu class.

Comment: ok , then provide the `script` , may be that `script` have some issue

Comment: @Slim_Shady if the log gives you 0px not null/undefined it means your script is correct. My feeling is your selector has comflicts like I mentioned. Try using .oriz_menu in your log and see what you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first create `#menu` and then `addClass` , Then append to parent div , like so

```
var menuDiv = "<div id='menu'></div>";
menuDiv = $(menuDiv).addClass("oriz_menu");

$("div#parent").append(menuDiv);

alert($("#menu").css("border-top-width"));
```

Check this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/P4QM2/)**

Comment: copied and pasted your code exactly.. I get alert: 0px

Comment: do you have div with id of `parent` in your `HTML` , only then this code works

Comment: yes I changed the id to parent.. Really don't know what is wrong.. the JSFIDDLE works

Comment: can you please provide your full `script`

Comment: it works now.. I was adding the class after logging the css.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/GNVGc/) is a JSFiddle with the answer.

HTML

```
<div id="menu"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$("#menu").addClass("oriz_menu");

alert(
    $("#menu").css("border-top-width")
);
```

Answer (score 1):

- in javascript

> var menuDiv = "";
>
> menuDiv = $(menuDiv).addClass("oriz_menu");
>
> $("div#parent").append(menuDiv);
>
> alert($("#menu").css("border-width"));

- in css

> .oriz_menu{
>
> font-size:18px;
>
> border:3px ridge darkred;
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

> Class name is not matching with CSS
>
> In CSS you are adding styles to".Class"
>
> But in jquery you are trying to add CSS for "#ID"
>
> please change the class name to "menu".

Now you can see the difference, Hope it helped you.

Comment: #menu is an ID not a class

Comment: please provide html and css ,i will try to fix it